# Drupal substracts 2 hours from the CCK date field when saving. Why?

Tags: entities, datetime

I have defined a CCK field of the date type with an Hour granularity
it looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

When I save it, it subtracts 2 hours from each one.

[image: screenshot]

I think it is caused from the set timezone.

My current timezone is "Europe/Madrid."

> Mac-Pro:~ usuario1$ date
>      martes, 13 de diciembre de 2011, 17:33:23 CET

The server's timezone is the same.

> Server:~ root$ date
>      mar dic 13 17:32:43 CET 2011

Why is Drupal doing this?

The dates have to be the same just as I type them.

Comment: If JimJamma's answer doesn't fix it, you may want to ask the question on the Ctools issue site at Drupal.org/project/ctools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Drupal 6 at least, you would go to admin/settings/date-time to check the default timezone of Drupal. I'd check to see if that's set correctly.  If it is, then you have to check if user configurable timezones are enabled, and if so, check what you or the logged in user has set in his/her account against all of the above.